# What identification document does the field legal_entity.personal_id_number designate?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect, stripe.net

I am trying to create a managed account for my user on Stripe Connect. I have been receiving different requests for different documents in the `verification.fields_needed` one at a time. I supply the one it says they need and then I get a new value in this field. So, my question(s) are:

1) Is there an exhaustive list of documents that are required for verification if the legal entity's country is US, so I can supply them to the API once and for all and not have to look at the additional documents requested in the Stripe response and send back another request? This makes it difficult to automate the process.

I referred to this document: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/required-verification-information

And supplied everything it asked for, but as you can see, `legal_entity.personal_id_number` isn't on that list and there is also no explanation for the meaning of this field.

2) What identification document does `legal_entity.personal_id_number` represent? The newest response I have received says it needs this to complete verification.

Comment: I got the same problem, I used to send the last 4 digit of the ssn number now the application is live and one user is unverified, when checked with login into stripe dashboard the account asked for legal_entity.personal_id_number. I dont know and when searched found this question on google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personal_id_number in the US is the full social security number, its only needed if the account is unable to be verified using the last 4 digits or if the account hits $20k in volume which would require Stripe to fill out a 1099K

https://support.stripe.com/questions/What-is-the-process-for-verifying-managed

Comment: Thank you, Matthew. I had read that page a few days ago. And as you and the page you linked to point out, I supplied all the basic information required. I am only just creating an account using my test Stripe secret key. The page says that it may require additional information such as full ID document if it cannot verify using SSN last 4. However, I live in India and don't have an SSN and am only trying to test the workflow so I can develop against it. What options do I have?

Comment: Also, please confirm that a platform can carry on performing transactions / charges on behalf of a managed account during the time the managed account's verification status is `unverified` as long as the value of the transactions is below the $20K cap?